# Is there a way to lock my browser with a password?

Tags: firefox, security, password, authentication

It would be OK if it was only with my login password, but I would like to lock both midori and Firefox so that they cannot be used without entering a password. I'm running 12.04.

Comment: You want to prevent *your* username from accessing firefox? Or block every other user except you from opening firefox?

Answer (score 7):

Use [ProfilePassword](http://nic-nac-project.de/~kaosmos/profilepassword-en.html) add-on for firefox. This would lock your firefox profile and whenever you run firefox it will ask for the password you set through add-on preferences.

Yes, these do not provide advanced security. But it's good enough just to prevent someone using firefox. I'm using it for some time now and had no problem yet.

Comment: Good suggestion!

Answer (score 5):

Even if you somehow lock just the browser but leave your computer/account logged in, it's quite possible for anyone to go in, open a terminal, and get the details of your Midori/Firefox history, cookies, stored passwords, etc.

**Therefore,** it's best to simply *lock* your screen/computer whenever you are not using it instead of ever leaving it open. Then your login password is required before anyone can do anything with the computer.

Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> keyboard shortcut to quickly lock the computer whenever you are not using it.

Comment: just wondering is there a way to allow only one user to access Browser using SUDO , i mean privileging  applications to run using sudo only :)

Comment: @tijybba: yes, just changing ownership to root and possible removing the execute permissions should do it -- but that still leaves the data open to anyone who can use a terminal...

Comment: @izx No need to use a terminal, just open a file browser and choose to show hidden files (dot-files). It's all right there.

Answer (score 1):

You can block users (that is, system identifiable users, e.g. users that are created using `adduser` command, that login separately etc) or users that don't belong in a group (here "webapps").

Find the executable file for firefox:

```
$ which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
```

Change mode (user permissions) from *755* (default) to *750* (not executable and not readable by "others" except for owner and group):

```
sudo chmod 750 /usr/bin/firefox
```

Create a group webapps:

```
sudo addgroup webapps
```

Add current user ($USER) in webapps group:

```
sudo adduser $USER webapps
```

You **have to logout/login** for changes to take effect.

You may add any other user, e.g. mytestuser:

```
sudo adduser mytestuser webapps
```

Change the owner and group from "root" (default) to "webapps":

```
sudo chown webapps:webapps /usr/bin/firefox
```

Try running firefox:

```
firefox
```

Your user can execute/open firefox, others cannot. If you logout/login with a different user that is not in "webapps" group, you won't be able to execute it.
Only users in the webapps group may execute /usr/bin/firefox now.

Revert changes using:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/firefox
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/firefox
```

Note: This doesn't stop the user from downloading a pre-compiled version of firefox (e.g. from http://www.mozilla.org).

Comment: `eviluser:~$ cat /usr/bin/firefox >~/firefox 2>&1 && chmod 755 ~/firefox && ~/firefox`

Comment: @MichaelKjörling How does 750 permission sound? :) Come to think of it, my answer doesn't stop the user from downloading a compiled version of firefox from https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/ and executing it :P